# Simple bundled products

Tags: magento2, bundle, bundle-product

Is there a way to make the bundled products in M2 behave like a simple product, except that the components are listed on the product page? Aheadworks has a module that almost does the job ([**link to screenshot**](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2018/12/05/m2_sbp__product.png)). The only problem is that the "available stock"-formula they have created leaves a lot to be desired. (They think that if only one of the components is in stock, then the whole bundle should also be in stock - even if two or three other components are missing).